# Get output from XML array

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm using XML for the use of different languages. First of all, I'm not used to work with XML so I want to ask if I'm doing it right. Here is my XML code:

```
<lang>
    <one>
        <ENG>Text1</ENG>
        <NL>Text2</NL>
    </one>
</lang>
```

When I load this in php I get this array:

> SimpleXMLElement Object ( [one] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [ENG] => Text1 [NL] => Text2 ) )

I'm now trying to get each single element out of the XML, I have this code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
$result = $xml['one']['ENG'];
```

But it doesn't return any result, please help.

Thanks.

Comment: http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic

Answer (score 1):

Use object accessor syntax instead:

```
$result = $xml->one->ENG;
```